# Trying to figure out a way to save integer/double variables from a text file with words mixed into the file

Tags: c++, file

So, I am trying to implement a function that can read a file and save some variables to it.  The text file will look like this

```
- Account Number: 12345678
- Current Balance: $875.00
- Game Played: 2
- Total Amount Won: $125.00
- Total Amount Loss: $250.00
```

So far, I am able to read the account number but when I try to read the rest using the same method, nothing gets outputted to the console.

Here is my progress so far.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int accNum;
    string accID;

    int games;
    double balance;
    double amountWon, amountLost;

    // Check if file with account number exists
    cout << "Please enter account number: ";
    cin >> accNum;

    // Append correct format to string
    accID.append("acc_");
    accID.append(to_string(accNum));
    accID.append(".txt");

    // Open the file
    inFile.open(accID);

    // Check if the account number exists
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Account number does not exist.\n";
    }


    int num;
    string str, str2, str3;

    // Read through the file
    while (inFile >> str >> str2 >> str3 >> num)
    {
        cout << num << " ";
    } 

    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I can get the account number to be output, but when I try adding more variables to read through the rest of the file nothing gets output to console.

Comment: You may want to read a whole line into a string with `std::getline()` and then parse the string. That would be easier than dealing with a variable number of white spaced separated strings followed by a number.

Comment: how would i iterate to the next line using getline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline` to read the rest of the file as shown below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
    int accNum;
    string accID;

    int games;
    double balance;
    double amountWon, amountLost;

    // Check if file with account number exists
    cout << "Please enter account number: ";
    cin >> accNum;

    // Append correct format to string
    accID.append("acc_");
    accID.append(to_string(accNum));
    accID.append(".txt");
    std::cout<<accID<<std::endl;

    // Open the file
    ifstream inFile(accID);
    if(inFile)
    {
        std::string strDash,strTitle, strNumber;
        int num;
    
        // Read through the file
        while (std::getline(inFile, strDash, ' '),//read the symbol -
        std::getline(inFile, strTitle, ':'),      //read the title(for eg, Account number,Current Balance etc)
        std::getline(inFile, strNumber, '\n'))    //read the number at the end as string
        {
            
                std::cout<<strDash<<" "<<strTitle<<strNumber<<std::endl;//print everything read
                
        }
    }
    // Check if the account number exists
    else
    {
        cout << "Account number does not exist.\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/giNetdJWH).